Generalized Leibniz rule for Sobolev functions - Reference request
For $p,q\in [1,\infty]$ one should have the following inequality as a consequence of the generalized Hölder-inequality.
If $f \in W^{1,p}$ and $g\in W^{1,q}$ then
$$
 \| fg\|_{W^{1,r}} \leq \|f\|_{W^{1,p}} \|g\|_{L^q} + \|f\|_{L^p} \|g\|_{W^{1,p}} 
 $$
for $\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}$. Does anyone know a reference for this fact?
Moreover, I think there should be a more general result if we assume
$f\in W^{1,p}\cap L^q$ and $g\in W^{1,\tilde{p}}\cap L^{\tilde{q}}$. Is this true, i.e. do we have $fg \in W^{1,r}\cap L^h$ for a suitable relation of $p,q,\tilde{p}, \tilde{q}, r$ and $h$? Maybe someone can provide a reference. Thanks in advance.

I think it does matter whether the region you are working on a bounded region.

Such a statement is true (also for unbounded domains). One uses density of $C^\infty(\Omega) \cap W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$  to prove that the weak derivative of $fg$ is given by the usual identities. Then Hoelder inequality to get whatever integrability is required for the derivative of the product.

Yes the statement should be correct independent of the domain. Nevertheless, I need mainly a reference for such inequalities to cite.
